# Absolute positioned element which does not escape viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a tooltip element which is displayed when hovering over certain elements.

I would like the tooltip to be positioned above the normal element as expected but in the case where the tooltip is too large and escapes the window, I need this to NOT happen.

How can I have an element which is absolutely positioned and also never displays out of view?

Edit: Preferably using CSS...

Comment: If the tooltip follows the mouse, then just set the width to its current width - half the width + pixels the mouse is away from the left or right.

Comment: I'd rather its width didn't change. I should be more clear - it's not that its width is too large, it's that when you hover over an element that is at the very right/left/top.. etc of the page - the tooltip is shown outside of the viewport.

Comment: So do you mean the tooltip doesn't show, or positions itself to fit?

Comment: You will need to use JS to get a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea presented here: [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport#123999)

I'd got with:

```
function elementInViewport(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top >= window.pageYOffset &&
    left >= window.pageXOffset &&
    (top + height) <= (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    (left + width) <= (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth)
  );
}

var tooltip = $(".tooltip");
tooltip.show(); //we must make it visible in order to perform the test on the next line
if(!elementInViewport(tooltip)) {
  tooltip.hide();
}
```